# Why do I get unauthorized for REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I setup the admin to access resources through REST API.
Here is my current setup:
 [image]

Then I assigned a Role user for the admin:

[image]

When I login as an admin and try to access the REST API, I still get unauthorized as seen here:

[image]

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567915/magento-access-denied

Comment: I tried all this, still getting the same error message. I am using the C# client from https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The URL passed for authorization has to be over https, otherwise you get the error message.

```
https://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize
```

Comment: can you pls help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334 @MBen